# How should I communicate with a server?

Tags: clojure, pedestal

Imagine some fellow wants to query a pizza server for the list of pizzas. This individual would do simply

```
 GET /pizzas
 ;=> ["cheese", "extra cheese", "broccoli"]
```

With *pedestal-app*'s data model and messages, I am not sure how to design client-server communication. Here are the possibilities some minutes of hammocking brought:

1. An **effect-consumer** that

   - transforms a message into an HTTP request
   - transforms back the results (to e.g. `[{:type :add :topic [:pizzas] :value "cheese"} ...]`)
   - puts the messages in the queue
2. A **dedicated resource on the server** (*e.g.* "/edn") that

   - accepts pedestal messages
   - dispatches to the right function
   - responds with the raw data (*i.e.* ["cheese", "extra cheese", "broccoli"])
   - has the effect-consumer transform back the results to messages
3. A **dedicated resource that uses the routes**. Just like #2, but

   - altering the request
   - forwarding it to another entry in route table
4. **Messages on both sides**, with

   - the server transforming messages into function calls
   - the server transforming results back into messages
   - the client just adding these messages to the queue

It seems to me that with approaches #2 and #4, I'd bypass and lose all the benefit of the interceptors. With approach #2, I'd need to redouble the routing logic. With approach #4, I'd also need to generate a lot of code to accommodate the pedestal client.

Options #1 and #3 seem better, but #3 smells hacky and #1, misdirected.

How are you guys doing it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about pedestal, I've been working in ring/compojure/etc.

With ring you can trivially wrap things use `ring.middleware.json` and putting    `ring.middleware.json/wrap-json-response` and `ring.middleware.json/wrap-json-params` around your pages, then inbound json data will be parsed into the parameters and you can return json as:

```
(ring.util.response/response ["cheese", "extra cheese", "broccoli"])
```

If your library doesn't support these kinds of behaviors you could probably extract the relevant code from ring etc.